# Want to show data that have been save in log file first instead of all?

Tags: bash, shell

I am working on a script that automatically blocks and shows the blocked IP address. But the problem is the blocked IP address is getting repeated every time I execute that script.

#### My code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

FILE=/var/log/suricata/fast.log

comod=`grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' $FILE | sort -u > /var/log/Blacklist/blacklist.log`  

iptables -F
cat /var/log/Blacklist/blacklist.log | while read ip 
do
  if [[ $ip != 192.168.0.105 && $ip != 192.168.0.1 ]] ; then
    iptables -A INPUT -s $ip -j DROP

    echo -e $ip"\t" "Auto Blocked\t" `(date +'%d/%m/%Y')`"\t" `(date +'%H:%M:%S %p')`  >> ban.log
  fi

done
```

#### Output:

```
0.0.0.0  Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:43:09 AM
104.16.112.18    Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:43:09 AM
104.244.42.200   Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:43:09 AM
118.214.143.208  Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:43:09 AM
192.168.0.100    Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:43:09 AM
192.168.0.101    Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:43:09 AM
192.168.0.102    Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:43:09 AM
192.168.0.104    Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:43:09 AM
192.168.0.106    Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:43:09 AM
192.168.0.108    Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:43:09 AM
216.58.199.162   Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:43:09 AM
224.0.0.1    Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:43:09 AM
224.0.0.251  Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:43:09 AM
239.2.0.252  Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:43:09 AM
64.233.166.94    Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:43:09 AM
0.0.0.0  Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:44:10 AM
104.16.112.18    Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:44:10 AM
104.244.42.200   Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:44:10 AM
118.214.143.208  Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:44:10 AM
192.168.0.100    Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:44:11 AM
192.168.0.101    Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:44:11 AM
192.168.0.102    Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:44:11 AM
192.168.0.104    Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:44:11 AM
192.168.0.106    Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:44:11 AM
192.168.0.108    Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:44:11 AM
216.58.199.162   Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:44:11 AM
224.0.0.1    Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:44:11 AM
224.0.0.251  Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:44:11 AM
239.2.0.252  Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:44:11 AM
64.233.166.94    Auto Blocked    19/04/2016  00:44:11 AM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a test to check if ip is already logged in by grepping in your `ban.log` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
[...]

# empty your ban.log file
echo "" > ban.log

cat /var/log/Blacklist/blacklist.log | while read ip
do
  #count occurrences of current ip in ban.log
  EXISTS=`grep "$ip" ban.log | wc -l`
  if [[ "$EXISTS" -gt 0 ]] ; then
     #debugging for better understanding
     echo "duplicate ip=$ip ignored"
  else
    if [[ "$ip" != "192.168.0.105" && "$ip" != "192.168.0.1" ]] ; then
      echo -e $ip"\t" "Auto Blocked\t" `(date +'%d/%m/%Y')`"\t" `(date +'%H:%M:%S %p')`  >> ban.log
    fi
  fi
done
```